# Windows Software to access Linux partitions from Windows

Tags: windows, windows-7, file-management

I frequently feel like accessing my files on Ubuntu from Windows. But Windows does not show Linux partitions while the reverse works.

Is there some software for Windows that can help me see Linux partition in Windows?

My OSs are Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04, I am using ext4 as my file system.

Comment: Linux supports many file systems and you'll need different drivers on windows depending on which it is. The default for Ubuntu seems to be [ext4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4). Are you using ext4?

Comment: Yes I am using ext4.

Comment: By "see" do you mean read & write access?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a very good software called [ext2fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/), but beware that writing to a partition using this may cause trouble. It did once on my system. I had to restart multiple times to get back to my ubuntu. For read only the software is awesome.
See this link for more details: http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/

Comment: For exactly that reason, when write access is required, you should have a dedicated "data partition" to exchange data – using a format both ends can deal with. Must not be FAT: Linux can deal fine with NTFS AFAIK.

Comment: Linux is open source. I don't understand why writing to an ext partition on Windows should cause any trouble. Didn't the developers implement everything?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [DataAccess FTK Imager](https://accessdata.com/product-download/ftk-imager-version-4-5).

Basically it's a computer forensic tool so the usability may not be ideal. And the file system is read only.

I use it to have a look at SD cards of my Raspberry Pi:

[image: FTK Imager screen shot]